# wondering why my GUI check button function is not working?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
class checkbutton:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main = tkinter.Tk()
        self.top = tkinter.Frame(self.main)
        self.bot = tkinter.Frame(self.main)

        self.cb1v = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.cb2v = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.cb3v = tkinter.IntVar()

        self.cb1v.set(0)
        self.cb2v.set(0)
        self.cb3v.set(0)

        self.cb1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top, text = 'Option 1', variable = self.cb1v)
        self.cb2 = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top, text = 'Option 2', variable = self.cb2v)
        self.cb3 = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top, text = 'Option 3', variable = self.cb3v)
        
        self.cb1.pack()
        self.cb2.pack()
        self.cb3.pack()

        self.calbutton = tkinter.Button(self.bot, text = 'ok', command = self.show)
        self.quit = tkinter.Button(self.bot, text = 'quit',command = self.main.destroy)

        self.calbutton.pack(side='left')
        self.quit.pack(side='left')
        tkinter.mainloop()

    def show(self):
        self.messge = 'you click: '
        if self.cb1v.get() == 1:
            self.messge = self.messge + '1'
        if self.cb2v.get() == 1:
            self.messge = self.messge + '2'
        if self.cb3v.get() == 1:
            self.messge = self.messge + '3'

        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('seletion',self.messge)

gui = checkbutton()
```

above is my code for checkbutton GUI program, I was expecting to get the output:
[image]

but after I run my program, the output is unexpected:
[image]

As you can see, my unexpected output is showing blank and not showing anything. I want to know why is that and is there anything wrong with my code? I will be very appreciated if you can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not packing the parent of `self.cb1` or `cb2` or `cb3`. You should do `self.top.pack()` in the `__init__` method.

```
def __init__(self):
    # code above
    self.top.pack()
    self.cb1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top, text = 'Option 1', variable = self.cb1v)
    self.cb2 = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top, text = 'Option 2', variable = self.cb2v)
    self.cb3 = tkinter.Checkbutton(self.top, text = 'Option 3', variable = self.cb3v)
    # code after
```

Comment: thank you, I was just copying the code straight from textbook but there were no top pack or bot pack() attributes. also do we always pack the frame when we created it?

Comment: @MINO if you want it to display you should  `.pack` or `.grid` it.